# nginx replace string in memcache cache

Tags: nginx, memcached

Need to replace some string in cache i get from memcache with some query string variable via nginx. how can I do it with exists solutions or should I write my own module?

Answer (score 0):

Are you tried to use http://sysoev.ru/nginx/docs/http/ngx_http_memcached_module.html ?

Comment: that's can't replace strings.